# Asp.Net I cant fill the DataTable ///OR\\\ My Procedure (oracle) doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I've write a procedure for login which getting parameter from asp Login.aspx. I also have a function for sending parameter and getting results. I think i can send the parameters but when datatable filling, throwing an error. I tryed something on c# side but i couldnt figure it. PS:I'm not sure if i execute my procedure. But procedure seems right.

```
public bool RunLoginProcedure(string E_mail, string PassWord)
    {
        OracleConnection connect = myconnection();
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
        OracleDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        command.Connection = connect;

        //OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[]
        //{
        //    new OracleParameter("@EMail",E_mail),
        //    new OracleParameter("@UserPassword",PassWord)
        //};

        //command.Parameters.Add(parameters);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMail", OracleDbType.NVarchar2));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UserPassword", OracleDbType.NVarchar2));
        command.Parameters["EMail"].Value = E_mail;
        command.Parameters["EMail"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters["UserPassword"].Value = PassWord;
        command.Parameters["UserPassword"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.CommandText = "Procedure_Login";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //here
        command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        bool value;

        if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            value = true;
        }

        else value = false;


        connect.Close();
        connect.Dispose();


        return value;
    }
```

and here my procedure

```
create or replace procedure Procedure_Login
(
EMail IN USERS.E_MAIL%TYPE,
UserPassword IN USERS.USERPASSWORD%TYPE,
id OUT VARCHAR2,
firstname OUT VARCHAR2,
lastname OUT VARCHAR2
) is
begin

SELECT USER_ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME 
INTO id,firstname,lastname
FROM USERS 
WHERE E_MAIL=EMail AND USERPASSWORD=UserPassword;

end Procedure_Login;
```

> And here is the error:
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpKnd.png)
>   Edit:view error more specific[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t3K9.png)

Comment: More information is displayed if you the "View details" link in the error (see also inner exception if not null).

Comment: i think you have oracle client problem so for more information refer this url https://community.oracle.com/message/10610812#10610812 for oracle client.

Comment: Show us the error as plain text.

Comment: You do not have to excecute ExecuteNonQueryAsync. See the [OracleDataAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm) help page for a simple code example.

Comment: I've edited the post and now u can see the detail of error. Mr. Radadiya; i had some problem about it but i figured it yesterday(i think) because the connection is working, i can see. Mr. Heier; Actualy im not sure how can i execute the procedure from here. I'm gonna check your adapter link now.

Comment: Edit: I know u are still cant see the error message, sorry. In detail, message says:Wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'Procedure_Login' ORA-06550 line1 column 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply your are calling a stored procedure that expect five parameter (2: input, 3: output), but you pass it only 2 input parameters..

```
create or replace procedure Procedure_Login
(
      EMail IN USERS.E_MAIL%TYPE,
      UserPassword IN USERS.USERPASSWORD%TYPE,
      id OUT VARCHAR2,        <--- miss in your calling code! 
      firstname OUT VARCHAR2, <--- miss in your calling code! 
      lastname OUT VARCHAR2   <--- miss in your calling code! 
) is
begin
 ...    
end Procedure_Login;
```

you should add at your code before `command.ExecuteNonQuery` or `.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` these lines...

```
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Id", OracleDbType.NVarchar2));
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("firstname", OracleDbType.NVarchar2));
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("lastname", OracleDbType.NVarchar2));

 command.Parameters["Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 command.Parameters["firstname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 command.Parameters["lastname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: @FurkanAyık Hi, may you give me any feedback, please?

Comment: I'm sorry for that late answer. I didnt use prosedure for this module, but i think u are right. It was about my prosedure. Because i got same error when i wrote wrong sql command. I have some job now, but i'll try your solution. And im pretty sure it will work. Thanks for help Mr. Corvino

Comment: Thank you Mr Ayik. I assure you that the problem reported in the OP depends by  the wrong number of parameters passed when calling stored proc. Best regards Ciro Corvino

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution here, so want to tell what i've done. I couldnt execute my procedure (i think it is about i'm not similar to oracle-plql) So i decided to giving up to using procedure. I used OracleCommand inside to c# and make it same job in command. (This was easyer and i had known that, i just wanted to learn executing procedure in c#) So this is working now. I still dont know how to run procedure in c# and i think im gonna need to learn it soon or later. So if someone could solve this problem it would be great. Have a nice day